# MYSQL query conditional statement

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a problem with a query:
I have a table with a list of orders placed by customers

```
orders: customer_id, payment_method ...some other field
```

I need to extract the customer_id and a 'YES' if the customer has made ​​at least one payment with a specific mode of payment

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.customer_id, 
CASE WHEN o.payment_method = 10 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS credit_card
FROM orders AS o
WHERE o.year = 2012
ORDER BY o.customer_id
```

but in case the customer has made ​​payments with different payment methods are shown two records, one with 'YES' one with a 'NO'... it's possible to get only one value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   o.customer_id, 
         IF(MAX(IF(o.payment_method=10, 1, 0)) = 1, 'YES', 'NO') credit_card
FROM     orders o
WHERE    o.year = 2012
GROUP BY o.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join with group by and test for NULL in the joined table (untested):

```
SELECT customer_id, IF(p.customer_id IS NULL, 'NO', 'YES')
FROM orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders p ON o.customer_id = p.customer_id AND p.payment_method = 10
    AND p.year = 2012
WHERE o.year = 2012
GROUP BY o.customer_id
ORDER BY o.customer_id
```

Not sure if you need the `p.year = 2012` condition or not from the question.